# Using CRecordset::Open and determining if no records returned?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, crecordset

```
    CString strSQL = _T("");

    rAryStrMemo.RemoveAll(); // Type CStringArray

    strSQL.Format(_T("SELECT memo1, memo2, memo3, memo4, memo5 FROM [Congregation Speakers] WHERE Congregation='%s' AND Speaker='%s'"),
        theApp.FormatDBText(strCongregation),
        theApp.FormatDBText(strSpeaker));

    CRecordset *pRecords = new CRecordset(theApp.GetDatabase());
    if (pRecords->Open(CRecordset::snapshot, (LPCTSTR)strSQL, CRecordset::readOnly))
    {
        CString strMemo = _T("");
        GetFieldValue(pRecords, _T("memo1"), strMemo); rAryStrMemo.Add(strMemo);
        GetFieldValue(pRecords, _T("memo2"), strMemo); rAryStrMemo.Add(strMemo);
        GetFieldValue(pRecords, _T("memo3"), strMemo); rAryStrMemo.Add(strMemo);
        GetFieldValue(pRecords, _T("memo4"), strMemo); rAryStrMemo.Add(strMemo);
        GetFieldValue(pRecords, _T("memo5"), strMemo); rAryStrMemo.Add(strMemo);
    }

}
```

The function it calls:

```
inline void GetFieldValue(CRecordset *pRS, LPCTSTR lpszFieldName, CString &rstrValue)
{
    rstrValue = _T("");    // Fallback.

    if (pRS != nullptr)
    {
        CString strTemp ;
        pRS->GetFieldValue(lpszFieldName, strTemp);    // This will be not right.
        rstrValue = (LPCTSTR)strTemp ;    // Forcing this conversion corrects it.
    }
}
```

I learnt something new today. If the resulting `CRecordset` is empty it causes an "Invalid cursor state" exception. I mistakenly thought that if `Open` returned true that it had one or more records. Obviously not.

So, what is the right way to know that atleast 1 record was returned?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I do a `pRs->MoveFirst();` and then `!pRs->IsEOF()` is true if there is a record. I typically use it in a loop to iterate a set of records. `for (pRs->MoveFirst(); !pRs->IsEOF(); pRs->MoveNext() )`

Comment: Hi @lakeweb Thanks, I will have a look at doing something similar.

Comment: @lakeweb Works well. On reflection, my normal `while` loops just use `while(!pRS->IsEOF())`. So maybe I don't need to call `MoveFirst()` and directly test `IsEOF()`?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I don't remember the details. But to just open a recordset and assume it will be parked on the first record, or not a record is available, is iffy. I think, as I recall, IsEOF does not get set true without a previous move. I'd have to go digging, but it is like a rule in my head.

Comment: So, I checked it out. _Immediately after you call Open, if the recordset contains no records, IsEOF returns nonzero_ [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecordset-class?view=msvc-170#iseof). So they say you don't have to `MoveFirst`.

Comment: @lakeweb In my case I just found out that using a `for` loop and `MoveFirst` approach gave me an internal error. I have simply adjusted the loops to `while(!pRS->IsEOF())`.